# GWT Compsite's initWidget not applicable for DivElement

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, uibinder

I'm implementing MVP in my first GWT app using the [recommended API from their docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Views), and admittedly, am doing some [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) while scrambling to learn/understand the API:

```
public class DefaultSignInView extends Composite implements SignInView {
    private static DefaultSignInViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(DefaultSignInViewUiBinder.class);

    public DefaultSignInView() {
        // ERROR: The method initWidget(Widget) in the type Composite is not applicable
        // for the arguments (DivElement)
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    // Extends the UiBinder interface for this particular view.
    interface DefaultSignInViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<DivElement, DefaultSignInView> {
        // No-op.
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, the call to `initWidget` is a syntax/compiler error:

> The method initWidget(Widget) in the type Composite is not applicable for the arguments (DivElement).

Now in the documentation (linked above) they show that you should extend `UiBinder` without the generic arguments. But I've also seen examples that use the generics, and again, cargo culting it, I borrowed from another example that used `DivElement` as the first argument. So, a few questions:

1. Why am I getting this syntax error?
2. What can I change `DivElement` to (or what else would I have to change) to correct it, **besides** removing the generic arguments? And if the generic arguments are deprecated or are **truly** no longer used, can someone explain why? In that case I'll just `@SuppressWarnings`.
3. Would someone provide a clear, layman's explanation of what the code is doing here? I hate cargo culting my code.

Comment: Note: the docs on gwtproject have a formatting issue: the generics aren't HTML-escaped! (shame on us!) Better read [the source](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt-site/+/master/src/main/markdown/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.md) or read [the UiBinder docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Widget_World)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is specific, definitely qualifies as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and shows research.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely think you are looking in the wrong place. Try this [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Overview). Most of it is explained in the docs, still i will try to highlight a few points,

1. What you are trying to do is very simple example of a UiBinder template that contains no widgets, only HTML.
2. So not being a widget, you cannot add it to a panel as a widget, instead you need to do a direct DOM manipulation.

I am adding a my sample code below

```
public class ImageViewer implements EntryPoint
{

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
    SampleUI sampleUI = new SampleUI();
    sampleUI.setNameSpan(" Trying it out!!");

    Document.get().getBody().appendChild(sampleUI.getElement());
    }
}
```

SampleUI ui-binder

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder">
<ui:style>
    .important {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</ui:style>
<div>
    Hello,
    <span class="{style.important}" ui:field="nameSpan" />
</div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

SampleUI java

```
public class SampleUI extends UIObject
{

    private static SampleUIUiBinder uiBinder    =     GWT.create(SampleUIUiBinder.class);

    interface SampleUIUiBinder extends UiBinder<DivElement, SampleUI>
    {
    }

    private DivElement  root;

    @UiField
    SpanElement         nameSpan;

    public SampleUI()
    {
        setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    public DivElement getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public void setNameSpan(String firstName)
    {
        nameSpan.setInnerText(firstName);
    }
}
```